# Add listener to attribute directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that looks like this. It adds a class based on boolean.

```
.directive('gdShow', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            console.log(attrs.gdShow);
            if(attrs.gdShow === true){
                elem.addClass('gdShow');
            }else{
                elem.addClass('gdHide');
            }
        }
    };
```

I would like this directive to update the class whenever the attribute I'm passing to the dierctive updates. I pass it like this: `gd-show="{{posted}}"`

So something like a listener or a databinding. is what I'm looking for.

I tried to add

```
    scope: {
        ngShow: '=',
    },
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: scope: {
        gdShow: '='
    },
Then you can access is with "scope.gdShow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution is to use `attrs.$observe` method to watch for the attribute value changes. This doesn't require you to create isolated scope if you don't want to.

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/TA8ounY53gjWsdst0tkM?p=preview)</kbd>

```html
<div>
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="username" />
</div>

<div gd-show="{{username}}">HI!</div>
```

```js
app.directive('gdShow', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

      attrs.$observe('gdShow', function(gdShow){
        if(gdShow){
          elem.removeClass('hide');
        } else {
          elem.addClass('hide');
        }
      });

    }
  };

});
```

Comment: If we are trying to conditionally add a class then ng-class might be worth looking into.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

Anyway @Stewie answers the actual question well here.

Comment: I second @rdjs's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-class` to do such kind of things. The documentation is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).

why would you write another while there is still one available?

Comment: my actual case is more complex with delays etc. Thought that is just pure js, so I didn't want to bring that in to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the complication of your own directive, and use the existing directive, ngClass to do this from the template:

```
<any-element ng-class="{'gdShow': posted, 'gdHide': !posted}"></any-element>
```

Or you can use interpolation via `{}`:

```
<any-element class="{{posted ? 'gdShow' : 'gdHide'}}"></any-element>
```

Comment: my actual case is more complex with delays etc. Thought that is just pure js, so I didn't want to bring that in to the question.